# send json data from parent window to child window

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a button in my jsp page.Whenever i click on that button i am opening a new window.

> I am calling a ajax call in parent window after that i am opening
>   that new window.I want    to use that ajax response in the child
>   window.

I searched in SO .But i am unable to find the correct answer.Is it possible or not?If 
  possible how i can do that.I am trying to get the solution from past 3 hrs.Please help me .
  Thanks in advance....

Comment: Maybe you should fire the ajax call in the new window

Comment: is there any other possibilities

Answer (score 1):

If u r using jquery window popup then please understand that the jquery popup is just a div with higher z index. Secondly for actual browser u can acces parent window by .
    Window.opener

Comment: Refer window.opener in that case

Comment: Check this  stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top

Comment: i tried browser.name = JSON.stringify(results);  but the result is coming like string

Comment: Stringify will obeviously convert it to string ... what are u expecting

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using

```
 browser.name = JSON.stringify(results);//parent window

   JSON.parse(name) //in the child window
```

Comment: just another thought ..u can do same by putting result in a hidden div then accessing same using window.parent :) ..